# Generic function behaving differently in the same environment

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics, swift3

**NB**: similar questions deal with SDK generic functions. This one is about self-written generic function.

I have this generic function

```
extension Array {

    func findObject<T: Identifiable>(withID objectID: Int) -> (index: Int, object: T)? {
        for (index, object) in self.enumerated() {
            if let identifiableObject = object as? T {
                if identifiableObject.id == objectID {
                    return (index, identifiableObject)
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

`Identifiable` protocol only requires the object to have the parameter `id` (*{get set}*).
In the code I have several usages of this function, all looking like this

```
typealias ObjectInfo = (index: Int, object: SomeObject)

    func deleteSomething(withID someID: Int) {
            guard let objectInfo: ObjectInfo = someArray.findObject(withID: someID) else {
                return
            }

            // some code
            ...
        }
```

This code compiles and works ok.

But when I try to write a unit test for the extension and I try to use it in the test, the problem occurs. This is the test fragment:

```
@testable import WhatEverTarget

typealias ObjectInfo = (index: Int, object: IdentifiableMock)
...
var array: [IdentifiableMock]!
...
let targetID = 4
let objectInfo: ObjectInfo = array.findObject(withID: targetID)
```

`IdentifiableMock` is just a simple class that has `id` and nothing more.
This test fragment won't compile, giving me the error (on the last line):

*"No "findObject" candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'ObjectInfo (aka '(index: Int, object: IdentifiableObject)')'"*

Please, help me to find the reason for such inconsistency.

Comment: Your return type doesn't match. findObject returns an optional but you are assigning it to a non-optional. Either remove the `: ObjectInfo` and let Swift infer the type or add a ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Paulw11 in comments, I needed to add optionality (?). This helped. Thank you a lot.

As always, just a simple detail, forgotten, "spoiled" the code. 
I guess, the reason why I missed it is because in the working code there was no optionality, but it was not required since the `guard`-statement.